# Matrices and the structure theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

***Problem:***

Let $A \in Mat_{n \times n}$ over $K$ a field. Show that there exist non-constant monic polynomials $d_1(x),...,d_s(x) \in K[x]$ with $d_1(x)| · · · | d_s(x)$ and an invertible matrix $P \in Mat_{n \times n}$ over $K$ such that $PAP^{-1}$
is block diagonal, with the companion matrices of $d_1(x),..., d_s(x)$
on the diagonal.

***Thoughts:***

Considering $V=Mat_{n \times n}$ as a vector space over $K$,

and $T$ some endomorphism over this space, the primary decomposition theorem gives that 
as a $K[x]$-module

$V=K[x]v_1 \oplus...\oplus K[x]v_s$ where the annihilators of each
$v_i$ are the monic polynomials $d_1(x),..., d_s(x)$.

I am stuck here, if anyone has any tips or insights on how to proceed that would be great.

**Edit:** I have included a solution attempt that is quite different from my initial thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt at a solution. Also I mean in the fifth line the monic generators of the Annihilators of the $v_i$

[image]